# Server.Transfer() inside Global.asax file showing problem

Tags: asp.net

I am using Global.asax page for error handling. While there is an error I want to transfer to a Error page to show a friendly message. But it is not showing that page.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried like this:

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Exception exception = Context.Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();
        // TODO: Do something with the exception

        Context.Response.StatusCode = 500;
        Context.Server.Transfer("~/500.htm");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

make sure ur file exist... ShowErrorPage.htm 
try respone.redirect instead of server.transfer like....

```
Exception exception = Context.Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();
    Response.Redirect("~/ShowErrorPage.htm");
```